# Transform generic array to function parameters

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts 2 parameters, the first one is a function that accept `...args` and the second one is array that contain all `args`.

```
myFunc(function(a, b){

}, [
  0, // this should set type of a to number
  "string", // this should set type of b to string
]);
```

In this example type of `a` should be `number`, `b` should be `string`.

I try this code but in the end the type of `a` is `number | string`

```
function myFunc<Deps extends [...any]>(
    resolver: (...deps: Deps) => void,
    deps: Deps
)
{

}
```

So my question is how to map second parameter type to function args.

I try to use `as const` but it cause error.

Here is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQDwBECmADgM6L4AeU+YAJqQNoB0zAhmKgLoB8AFAFCJBiAE75icADYA3fMIBciHs0Y0ixBQRIBKRAF4uiKXBg0ANAKGqSGtXy18A3nz4BfZ2kyQePFqcQAjPwgdfUQnIUQAekjEKFRCOHxgRBZEYgALOBAJGgD8RDAQZH9ZPIgWEGJ8uGSARgtBaNj4xOT-NMzs3JK0qGEYMABzMoqqxBrEACIqYihJhqiYuISkxAgOrJy8gLhJfDYRyurkvpB8Vz96Wr9psTm-U-wOLQBuZ3ePLG9fAKCQg3CQiay1aKQ2XW2hWKpRK5SO4zqC2BLVW7Qym26+Vm-SGhzGE1us3mEWRK2S63REJ6-l2En2SFho2OsWEZwuiCuNxm9xZZw4KVIEAQs1eQA)

I know I can solve this problem like this

```
myFunc((a, b, c) => {
}, [1, "test"] as [number, string]);
```

But is there any way to infer it without explicit type hinting?

**UPDATED**

I found the answer, and its so weird for me, but its working without any extra steps.

I simply change `Deps extends [...any]` to `Deps extends [any, ...any]`, Even if I want empty array I could use `Deps extends [any?, ...any]` And its working perfectly

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQDwBECmADgM6L4AeU+YAJqQNoCGYqANIgHRfOoC6AfAAoAUIjGIATvmJwANgDd8EgFyJBXDjSLFVBEgEpEAXn6J5cGDVajxWkru3D9wgN7DhAX3dpMkQYMZ2ACN2CEMTRDdxRAB6GMQoVEI4fGBERkRiAAs4EFkaRCD8RDAQZCKJQvwIRhBiYrg0gEYbMTiEpJS0oMycvIKizKgJGDAAcyqauoa0gCIqYihZ1tj4xOTUxAhe3Pyqwrg5fGZJ2vrERoSJEHxPdnom9nnpJfZhm959AG53YSA)

I have no idea how this is working.
So my question is why is this working? this is somehow [any, ...any] somehow telling typescript to infer type of array as tuple?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely make use of [`const` type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to infer the array as an array of literal types, but this would result in the parameter types of the callback being literals, which we don't want.

A pretty simple fix would be to use a utility like this to effectively widen the literal type:

```
type Widen<T> = T extends string
    ? string
    : T extends number
    ? number
    : T extends boolean
    ? boolean
    : T; // add more cases if needed
```

And then you can map over `Deps` and widen each of its elements:

```
function myFunc<const Deps extends readonly unknown[]>(
    resolver: (...deps: { [K in keyof Deps]: Widen<Deps[K]> }) => void,
    deps: Deps,
) {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glgEwgOwDwBUB8UC8V1QQAewKCAzlOcAE5zIDmAUFK1APxW33NtQBc+QiTKVkAVwC2AIwg0WbThJlyFrQQWKlkFKNID2+gDYQAhsjUc9hk+csaA3FAD0zqKYQIok-TWgBjU3IISjgAMyhkCAgkBCYmMPFkf2A4fWRvEAAxJP9Uf3TqKAARCDBKLVEoPw90oxAoJIBrZH0Ad2QAbQBdTAAKSz9yYwA3OUE+gDpppHLBAG8oToBpKHooJogQfQjS8u7BeCQ0PfIV3qgAXwBKXGwR-UQAGktZ8kFTl9v5y-jJbNyAz4fVMTz0YP8txw2Hmlj4rigoDA+ggEVMVAAFvpxEYvLJIlJZDQ9BBAuJglAdlAAIxwtgIpEoiLSTHY3Ekrh0RgkskUqkAIlI1H5dNYDPATKg-lZOLx0AMxjMGVkvOgVNo4gglkuLz4nWpYMFIWA-LBGog3S+DiYQA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I solve my problem very simple, I updated my question can you look at it

Comment: I like the idea behind the `Widen` utility as long as the tuple member types are primitives. I think when any object type is needed in a tuple, that it will become difficult to use generically and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript's on-site inference is influenced by both the function signature (including how its [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) are written), and by the types of the arguments used at the call site of the function.

From [the TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters):

> When inferring the type of an object, TypeScript will usually choose a type that’s meant to be general.

You stated that you want TS to infer the type of the second argument as a tuple of `[number, string]` without annotation. TypeScript does not currently offer a way to do this: it can either infer the unannotated array object as an array or tuple consisting of members whose types are a union of each of the array member types (`number | string`), or it can [infer literally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference) so that it is a tuple of `readonly [0, "string"]`.

However, there are changes you can make to the code to influence the inference.

For example: by providing explicit type annotations on the parameters of the resolver function at the call site, TypeScript can infer the tuple as desired:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQDwBECmADgM6L4AeU+YAJqQEr4CGNCANqgIIBO3Tq2JmFQA+EQAoAUIkTd8xOGwBu+bgC5E4gHQ6aRYhoIkAlIgC8IxErgwaAGmmI9JQ-oemA3gF9JktJkgpAHoggD0AfkdQSFgETSYNMBBkACNVO0QUjWIobhgwAHNPLwcZAG0ABgyAIhy8wuqAXXcAbkkgA)

```ts
function myFunc<Deps extends ReadonlyArray<any>>(
  resolver: (...deps: Deps) => void,
  deps: Deps,
) {}

myFunc(
  function (a: number, b: string) {},
  [0, "string"],
);

/*

The type of the function at the call site above is:

function myFunc<[a: number, b: string]>(
  resolver: (a: number, b: string) => void,
  deps: [a: number, b: string],
): void

*/
```

The above is idiomatic and achieves the desired outcome.

Alternatively, you can use a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) and TS will use [literal inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference) (which will result in types that might be too narrow for the logic in the resolver function body, depending on that logic):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQDwQQZykQBEBTAB30VIA8pSwATKgJVIENGEAbVAQQBOA9qmzswqAHySAFAChEiAaXxxuAN1ICAXIhkA6Q4wr5dZSgEpEAXkmJ1cGIwA0CxMcpmTrqwG8AvnJyaJiQ8gD04QB6APxuoJCwCHrszogARn7+rooA2gAMaQBEhAIwYADmRQC6PgDcckA)

```ts
function myFunc<const Deps extends ReadonlyArray<any>>(
  resolver: (...deps: Deps) => void,
  deps: Deps,
) {}

myFunc(
  function (a, b) {},
  [0, "string"],
);

/*

The type of the function at the call site above is:

function myFunc<[a: 0, b: "string"]>(
  resolver: (a: 0, b: "string") => void,
  deps: [a: 0, b: "string"],
): void

*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I solve my problem very simple, I updated my question can you look at it

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340501/transform-generic-array-to-function-parameters/77340703#comment136345803_77340703) @AliAkbarAzizi Your recent [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77340501/5) substantially changes the original question. It's more appropriate to ask a new question with the different information.